# How do you reference/use custom JARs in an HDInsight Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter, azure-hdinsight

How do I use a custom JAR inside a Jupyter notebook on my HDInsight cluster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classpath (and other settings) for a Jupyter session running in HDInsight are configurable through a cell magic call to `%%configure`

Any setting supported by [the Livy Session API](http://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#post-batches) can be set here.

For example, if you had a JAR at the root of your cluster's default storage called `foo.jar`, you could reference it for inclusion like so:

```
%%configure -f
{"jars": ["/foo.jar"]}
```